# How to prove $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{AB}-\mathbf{I}) \leq \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})+\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{I})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Letting $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be $n$-square complex matrices, I try to prove the problem such as

$\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{AB}-\mathbf{I}) \leq \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})+\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{I})$

described in p.49 of "Matrix Theory: Basic Results and Techniques.".

I consider

$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{I}=(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})(\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{I})+(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})+(\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{I})$

and the subadditivity of the rank, but it wasn't successful.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Write instead $AB-I = (A-I)B + (B - I)$. What do you know about the rank of $(A-I)B$?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, Mr. Bhuyan.

I rewrite

$\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{I}) 
=\operatorname{rank}((\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})\mathbf{B}+(\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{I}))
\leq
\operatorname{rank}((\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})\mathbf{B})+\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{I}))$,

and from

$\operatorname{rank}((\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I}), \mathbf{B}) 
\leq 
\operatorname{min}(\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{B}))
\leq
\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I}))$,

I just obtain

$\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{AB}-\mathbf{I})
\leq 
\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})
+
\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{B}-\mathbf{I})$,

Q.E.D.